# efficient way to send a temporary message from admin to a specific user in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i'm trying to send a temporary message/alert for a specific user on my app.
I've managed to do it using this approach and i wanna know if there is an efficient/easier way to do it .

## models.py

```
class Indar(models.Model):

    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='indars')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    start   = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end     = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

## views.py

```
 def home(request):
        qs = Indar.objects.filter(start__lte=timezone.now().date(),end__gte=timezone.now().date(),user=request.user)
        Indar.objects.filter(end__lte=timezone.now().date()).delete()
        return render (request, 'home.html' , {'qs':qs})
```

## home.html

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">

    {% for obj in qs %}

            {{ obj.content }}
    {% endfor %}

 </div>
```

Comment: Tried messaging framework?

Comment: messagin framework work after an event  and display the message one time only ,but what i'm looking for is a user friendly way to display a message for a certain time from the admin . i do know that my code works but i dont think that how an experienced dev would do it